# How to call a Generic procedure recursively with delphi and RTTI?

Tags: delphi, rtti

I'm working on Delphi 10.2 Tokyo and facing the following situation:

Assuming I have the following procedure, to verify the properties of an object:

```
procedure TGenericUnit.VerifyProps<T>(_AObj: T);
var
   AContext: TRttiContext;
   AType: TRttiType;
   AProp: TRttiProperty;
begin
   AType := AContext.GetType(T);
   for AProp in AType.GetProperties do
      if AProp.PropertyType is TObject then
         // VerifyProps<?>(?);  
end;
```

If I don't know which type of object it will be and it won't necessarily be the same as T, how could I call this procedure recursively?

Comment: To get an actual property, you need to get it on an instance of a class, in this case _AObj. But as others have said, you'll need to test for IsInstance, and then AProp.GetValue(_AObj). You can use the TValue to get an object. But that has its own type, so no recursion possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do all your work in a non generic method working with `TObject`.
You can get the type from `AObj.ClassType` or `AObj.ClassInfo` passing that to `AContext.GetType`.

By the way your check `if AProp.PropertyType is TObject then` is wrong because yes of course PropertType is a `TObject` (it is an `TRttiType` object). What you probably mean is `if AProp.PropertyType.IsInstance then` (is the type of the property a class type)

Answer (score 3):

Generics are a compile time construct. The type parameters must be resolved at compile time. Since you don't know the type at compile time you can't call the generic method.

Instead of using a generic method, you will have to implement this using RTTI. Instead of using a generic parameter to specify the type, use a standard parameter of type `TRttiType`.